# How to delete a row from two tables using Id if exist SQL

Tags: java, sql, psql

I have 2 tables; 1 named student and 1 named student_course. I want to delete an entry using the student ID which is the same for both tables, but an student can or can not be enrolled in a course meaning they are not in the table student_course. How do I delete the student from both tables or just from the student table if he is not in any course?
This is what I have in mind:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM student, student_course" +
                "USING student INNER JOIN student_course" +
                "ON student.student_id = student_course.student_id" +
                "WHERE student.student_id =?";
```

Comment: Simply use [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php) on the foreign key constraint, then it will do the job for you.

Comment: This syntax is not valid in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can delete from multiple tables using CTEs:

```
with d as (
      delete from student_course sc
          where sc.student_id = ?
     )
delete s from student s
    where s.student_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **ON DELETE CASCADE** option on the foreignkey. If you specify the foreign key like this:

ALTER TABLE student_course
ADD FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(student_id) **on delete cascade**;

it automatically deletes your records in student_course if you delete records in students.